# Unable to cast system int to system string in c#

Tags: c#

I am getting this error when retrieving a string value from the database. I am casting to a string value.

This code worked in VS 2005 and VS 2008, but when I try to run it in VS 2017, I get the error.

Here is the code

```
       private void GetExplanation(Card c, int position)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
            {
                CommandText = "usp_PCGetExplanation"
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@positionID", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@cardNumber", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters["@positionID"].Value = position;
            cmd.Parameters["@cardNumber"].Value = c.CardValue + 1;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();


                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                rdr.Read();

                if (rdr.HasRows)
                {
                    c.Explanation = rdr.GetString(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Unable to get explanation");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format(
                    "Error retrieving explanation {0}", ex.Message));
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Here is the **Card** class attributes

```
    public class Card
    {
        public static string[] faceValues = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four",
                                            "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight",
                                            "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

        public static string[] suits = { "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Spades" };

        private int cardValue;

        private string faceName;
        private string suitName;
        private string explanation;

        public bool isNegative;

        private Image cardPicture;

        private readonly Random rnd = new Random(52);

        public Card(int value)
        {
            cardValue = value;
            faceName = faceValues[(value) % 13];
            suitName = suits[value / 13];
            explanation = " ";
        }

        public int CardValue
        {
            get { return cardValue; }
            set { cardValue = value; }
        }

        public string FaceName
        {
            get { return faceName; }
            set { faceName = value; }
        }

        public string SuitName
        {
            get { return suitName; }
            set { suitName = value; }
        }

        public string Explanation
        {
            get { return explanation; }
            set { explanation = value; }
        }

        public Image CardPicture
        {
            get { return cardPicture; }
            set { cardPicture = value; }
        }

        public int FaceValue
        {
            get { return cardValue % 13; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} of {1}", FaceName, suitName);
        }
        public bool IsNegative
        {
            get
            {
                if ( suitName == "spades")
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And here is the stored procedure

```
USE [PersonalForecast]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_PCGetExplanation]    Script Date: 3/21/2019 5:28:16 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Tom Magaro
-- Create date: 20101214
-- Description: Gets the PositionCard row
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_PCGetExplanation] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @positionId int, 
    @cardNumber int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT Explanation
    FROM   PositionCard
    WHERE  PositionId = @positionId and
           CardId = @cardNumber
    ORDER BY positionId, CardId
END
```

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated

Tom

Comment: `position` is passed in as an `int`, and the stored procedure expects an `int`, so why make the parameter a `varchar`?

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `position`?

Comment: It can be 1-13. I have made the change, but still getting the error

Comment: Please update your question to show your current code. Also make clear **what exact exception you are getting, and on what line of code you are getting it**.

Comment: The error was an Invalid Cast Exception.  Why it was returning this error is beyond me as I was equating a string to a string, but I believe having the parameters initialized was causing SQLServer to return an integer value.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is on your parameter type. `@positionID` might be int because your parameter is int in your stored procedure

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@positionID", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@cardNumber", SqlDbType.Int);
```

c# parameters type is the match on stored procedure parameter type.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, good catch.  However, after making the change, I am still getting the error

Answer (score -1):

The error was in the stored procedure.

@positionId int = 0,
@cardValue int = 0

should have been

@positionId int,
@cardValue int

Comment: I would be incredibly surprised if that explains what you are seeing.

Comment: I am particularly surprised that the second parameter changed its name somehow (from `cardNumber`).

Comment: I admit, when I wrote this application, I was not that experienced in C# and had little experience with SQLServer, so I was a bit inconsistent in my naming conventions.  Both represent the same value.